# Display pop-up in onClick

Tags: javascript, lightning, jquery

I have matrix, if criteria matches from x-axis and y-axis the value for particular cell increases.
Now I want to show pop-up if I click on the cell. Pop-up will contain the link for the records from that cell[image]

here in matrix some cell have 28 records, some have 4 so on click how can I show pop-up with the link for each record